# How do I make the keyboard associated w/ a UITextField have a transparent background?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I would like the keyboard that is displayed when the user is typing in a UITextField to have a transparent background so the user can see the image under the keyboard. The keys would need to remain non-transparent and just the background, i.e., gray filler color around the keys be transparent.

Comment: My friend showed me the AOL app w/ such a keyboard which is where I got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to do what you want to do and I'm not sure you can make the standard keyboard have a transparent background however you should be able to create you own custom keyboard with transparent background as a view controller and then use the inputView property of the UITextField to replace the standard keyboard with your own custom one.

1. Create a view controller with associated xib that functions as your custom keyboard.
2. In the initialisation of the screen with the UITextView do something like

   MyCustomKeyboardViewController *kbvc = [[MyCustomKeyboardViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyCustomKeyboardViewController bundle:nil];

   myTextView.inputView = kbvc.view;

   [kbvc release];

Just make sure all components in your custom keyboard xib have the background colour set to ClearColor.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I would rather not create a custom keyboard. Hopefully there is a property in the standard keyboard that exposes the background layer.